# looping through charts as frames in plotly

Tags: animation, plot, charts, plotly

There are [nice introductions](https://plot.ly/python/animations/) to animations in plot.ly out there. However, no examples of this case: flipping through (bar) charts plotting different years of similar data (e.g., different columns of some 100 rows). Isn't it what grids and columns are supposed to do? How does one define such a structure?

Comment: Could you use a [slider](https://plot.ly/python/animations/#using-a-slider-and-buttons) to add a plot at each interval?

Comment: Eh, probably…  (That is not a simple example either, but I should work on it.)